# Asana Task Permissions

Tags: api, asana

I am connecting to the Asana API endpoint and creating a task independent from anything except I am putting in into my company workspace.

I see that it has the permission "private" but I can change it to "public" on the UI in the site.  However, I want to make the task public upon my POST request to the /tasks endpoint.

This is because I don't necessarily want the user to have to specify a project to be able to POST a public task that is available for the whole company workspace to see.

How can I add this attribute to my task without associating with a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently support for this, but I'll add it to our feature wish list!